# Mysql fatal Error : Too many connections with php

Tags: php, mysql

problem with mysql_connect() function .. when visitor load image in subject cause this Error

> Too many connections
>
> code number: 1040

and the max_connections is 500

PLZ what can i do ?
change this value to 1024 ?

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1024;
```

Or what ??
but why this problem Happen ??

Answer (score 1):

1- Open your MySql client, e.g. SQLyog.

2- Run the following command to see how  many concurrent connections is MySql server currently allowing:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
```

3- Run the following command to increase the number of concurrent connections:

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1000;
```

Another approach is:

Look in and modify your my.cnf file to change the max # of connections - watch out for memory/load issues.

PS: Whenever you open a MySQL connection, close it with `mysql_close()`.

Comment: max_connections is 500 in server

Comment: max_user_connections is 0